# 97 saturn sl1 and it wont turn over without me hitting the gas

Tags: engine

Ive replaced the ignition, alternator, timing belt, starter, ignition and the water pump. My car still wont roll over easily and i dont know what else could be wrong.  My radiator leaks all the antifreeze within 5 minutes and it wont start without me pushing on the gas fast a bunch of times. When it finally starts it has a burning smell coming from the radiator with a little bit of white smoke

Comment: You should probably recheck your timing and fix your radiator if it's leaking that bad.

Comment: What codes is it blowing?  The computer stuff is super important on an OBDII engine even if you do not live in a smog control state.  Keep the computer gear happy, it'll keep you happy.